# How to set text size according to the screen size in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, typography, screen-size, text-size

In my app I use one typography

```
val Typography = Typography(
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
        hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
        lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
    )
)
```

and it works fine. Now I added a support for different screen sizes (`val windowSize = calculateWindowSizeClass(this)`). Now I need to adjust text sizes in my app according to the current screen size.

How can I do it globally? Currently, I check the screen size for each `Text` view and set the wisched size, which is not effective and requires a lot of work, which looks like this:

```
...
val fontSize = when(windowSize.widthSizeClass) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> 14.sp
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> 16.sp
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> 18.sp
        else -> 14.sp
}

Text(text = "Some text...", fontSize = fontSize)
...
```

Is there an affective way to set the text size globally for all `Text` views within the app,for example something like this:

```
val Typography = when(windowSize.widthSizeClass) {
    WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> Typography(
        bodySmall = TextStyle(  // --------------------> Small for compact screens
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            lineHeight = 20.sp,
            letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
            hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
            lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
        )
    )
    WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> Typography(
        bodyMedium = TextStyle(  // --------------------> Medium for medium screens
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            lineHeight = 22.sp,
            letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
            hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
            lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
        )
    )
    WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> Typography(
        bodyLarge = TextStyle(  // --------------------> Large for Expanded screens
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            lineHeight = 24.sp,
            letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
            hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
            lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
        )
    )
    else -> bodySmall = TextStyle(  // --------------------> Small for compact screens
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            lineHeight = 20.sp,
            letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
            hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
            lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
        )
}
```

Is there a way to get it optimally done?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.